# How do I run two separate while loops in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

Say I have a while loop that prints me the time every second

```py
while True:
    print(strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z", gmtime())
    sleep(1)
```

and I have another while loop that lets me choose between menu options

```py
while not exit:
    choice = input("[1] " + "Menu1\n" +
                   "[2] " + "Menu2 \n" +
                   "[3] " + "Exit\n" + Fore.RESET)
    if choice == "1":
        menu_1(exit, args)
        return
    elif choice == "2":
        menu_2(exit, args)
        return
    elif choice == "3":
        print("Exiting...")
        exit = True
        return
    else:
        # invalid option
```

I want the desired result to have the time on top changing every second while allowing me to choose the menu options.

i.e.

```
Tue, 12 Jul 2022 06:38:56 PM GMT

[1] Menu 1
[2] Menu 2
[3] Exit
```

Comment: you don't need to separate loops for that, you can just add the statements of the first loop into the second loop, before `choice`

Comment: Thsi can be a challenge on a terminal because you need to control multiple lines. If its a unix/linux terminal it may respond to VT codes and you may want to use a package like `curses` to do it. But one usually moves to a GUI package for this type of thing.

Comment: @EnriqueBet they can't do that because `sleep()` won't allow any code after it perform until the second is done so it would only loop each second

Comment: @EnriqueBet - its more complicated than that. The time needs to be updated every second, but as soon as `input` is called, its going to block and the time update will be missing. And then there is the question of how you want to keep repeating the sreen update on a terminal.

Comment: Its easier if the time is placed below the menu items so you can use backspace on a single line to update.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiprocess. Then again I'm not sure this code will work but I know multiprocess could be the easiest solution. Refer to   [the Python documentation on multiprocessing for more information](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def a():
    while True:
    print(strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z", gmtime())

def b():
while not exit:
    choice = input("[1] " + "Menu1\n" +
               "[2] " + "Menu2 \n" +
               "[3] " + "Exit\n" + Fore.RESET)
    if choice == "1":
        menu_1(exit, args)
        return
    elif choice == "2":
        menu_2(exit, args)
        return
    elif choice == "3":
        print("Exiting...")
        exit = True
        return
    else:
        # invalid option

if __name__=='__main__':
    Process(target=a).start()
    Process(target=b).start()
```

Then again, I'm not sure if this will work or not as I have not tried it yet.